# How do I link an application for dynamic loading by RTEMS?

Tags: c, linker, dlopen, dlsym, rtems

I'm using [RTEMS](http://www.rtems.org/) 4.11 and the builtin POSIX API functions to dynamically load a program image into memory. The program image is loaded in RTEMS using the following code:

```
void* handle = dlopen(prog_name, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
if (!handle)
    printf("dlopen: %s\n", dlerror());
```

I'm using the GCC built by RTEMS Source Builder to compile the object located at `prog_name` in the in-memory filesystem.

**What command line should I use to properly compile a single C file to be loaded this way?**

For reference, I've tried the following command line options, but got an error:

```
$ /opt/rtems-4.11/bin/sparc-rtems4.11-gcc test.c -c -o test.elf -shared -fPIC -nostdlib
$ # dlopen: global symbol not found: _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_

$ /opt/rtems-4.11/bin/sparc-rtems4.11-gcc test.c -o test.elf -fPIC -shared -nostdlib
$ # dlopen: ELF file contains program headers
```

I have also tried some other combinations and also using the `rtems-ld` program. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the only important option is `-c` (compile and assemble but do not link).

```
$ /opt/rtems-4.11/bin/sparc-rtems4.11-gcc test.c -c -o test.elf
$ # this now works
```

[Credit](https://lists.rtems.org/pipermail/users/2018-September/032588.html)